# Extensible text based serialization for c#

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, nested

I'm looking for a text-based (i.e. human readable and not binary) extensible serialization for C#.

The number of items I want to save is rather small (<100). It would be ok to create additional classes for serialization that fill the really used classes after deserialization.

Standard built-in XML serialization is neither very easy to read and neither extensible I think.

I already looked at protobuf-net and it looked promising but since it's binary I dropped it.

I also tried [custom serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28VS.80%29.aspx) but couldn't manage to serialize two of a kind.

I also had a look at JSON.net but it didn't work better than custom serialization.

My data structure right now looks roughly like this:

```
class ClassIWantToSerialize
{
    DataContainer A;
    DataContainer B;
    DataContainer C;
    DataContainer D;
    DataContainer E;
    DataContainer F;
    double G;
    double H;
    // other stuff that I don't want to serialize...
}


class DataContainer
{
   MinorDataContainer A;
   MinorDataContainer B;
   double C;
   double D;
   double E;
   double F;
    // other stuff that I don't want to serialize...
}

class MinorDataContainer
{
   double A;
}
```

The problem arose when I tried to add the second `MinorDataStructure` (i.e. `B`) and it complained that it cannot add the same fields twice.

```
class DataContainer
{
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        A.GetObjectData(info, context);
        B.GetObjectData(info, context); // error upon calling this line
        info.AddValue("C", C);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your custom serialization and explain a bit what the problem with JSON was? - I think JSON is exactly what you want and it's quite easy to achieve too

Comment: +1 for JSON. I think that's the best solution. Easy to read, easy to implement.

Comment: @Carsten: I tried to serialize a UserControl which reported self references. I ended up making a easily serializable POD for each of the 3 classes I want to serialize and added `serializeTOPOD` and `derserializeFromPOD` members. I then serialize a class containing all relevant PODs with JSON.net. This works quite well so far. I still have to test what happens if I add a new member to serialize...

Comment: ... well things like UserControls are just not serializable - for example: how should it serialize the current Handles?

Comment: @Carsten: I didn't want to serialize the control but just the values of the `DependencyProperty`s used within. I export them to a POD during serialization now and import them back later upon deserialization.